# vue2 project failed compiling

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

How can I fix it? as the page not loading(showing a white page without anything else.)

```
WAIT  Compiling...                                                                                                                                                                                                    
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 WARNING  Compiled with 4 warnings                                                                                                                                                                                     
 warning  in ./src/main.js

"export 'createApp' was not found in 'vue'

 warning  in ./src/router/index.js

"export 'createRouter' was not found in 'vue-router'

 warning  in ./src/store/index.js

"export 'createStore' was not found in 'vuex'

 warning  in ./src/router/index.js

"export 'createWebHistory' was not found in 'vue-router'
```

I just fixed another issue and now I got this. How can fix it please?

Comment: Without more information about your environment and the relevant pieces of code this cannot be solved. Please add more info.

Answer (score 1):

Those errors imply that you're trying to use the Vue 3 API (i.e., `createApp`), but you have `vue@2.x` installed (the [vuejs2](/questions/tagged/vuejs2) tag is also a clue to that). Similarly, you're using Vue Router 4's API (i.e., `createRouter`), but you have `vue-router@3.x` installed.

### Solution

You can either install the newest versions of the dependencies:

```sh
npm i -S vue@3 vue-router@4
```

Or you can use the older APIs. That is, switch from Vue 3 / Vue Router 4 code:

```js
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

```js
// router.js
import { createRouter } from 'vue-router'

export default createRouter(/*...*/)
```

...to Vue 2 / Vue Router 3 code:

```js
// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from './router'

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

```js
// router.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter(/*...*/)
```